# Suggestions about how to handle recurring payments when packages involved

Tags: paypal

Please suggest the following:

when a user want a certain package in my site, let's call it basic package.. his starting his recurring payment..after half a month he canceles the package, but his still paid for a full month, my question is this:

When recurring payment involved, what kind of fields should i save from the ipn, and how should i know exactly when to stop the features of the package a user bought...

I've seen in the ipn, i have 'next recurring payment' date, should i save it and use it? should i, every time a user do anything related to his package,check if the package limit time just ended? 
What can be a most preferred solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When recurring payment involved, what kind of fields should i save from the ipn

All of them, for any kind of IPN whatsoever. Log the entire transaction every time.

> and how should i know exactly when to stop the features of the package a user bought...

You should definitely stop when you get a `cancel` or `eot` IPN message. You probably don't want to deny service just because of payment difficulties. See below for the rest of it.

> I've seen in the ipn, i have 'next recurring payment' date, should i save it and use it?

Save everything. Then you don't have a problem.

> should i, every time a user do anything related to his package, check if the package limit time just ended? What can be a most preferred solution for this?

I have a 'subscriptions' table which shows the user/product pair and the expiry date. Every time he pays the expiry date is pushed out another period, or maybe I create it with the final expiry date, I don't remember offhand. When he logs in, he is given the roles associated with all his subscriptions that haven't expired yet.

If he tries to do something he can no longer do due to an expiry:

- he isn't even provided with a link in the first place by the webapp, so he can't get there by any direct action
- in any other case, e.g. somewhere I forgot to do that, or when he tries to access via a bookmark, container-managed authentication will see that he isn't in the appropriate role and give him a 403.

He can also see a table of his subscriptions showing how long they have left to run, and another table of expired subscriptions.